# Wait until specific value appears in selenium excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have an element with this html

```html
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2" designtimedragdrop="1319" style="display:inline-block;color:Firebrick;font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;width:510px;"></span>
```

and after clicking Save button on the page this part changes to that

```html
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2" designtimedragdrop="1319" style="display:inline-block;color:Firebrick;font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;width:510px;">تم حفظ التعديل بنجاح</span>
```

You would notice this value `تم حفظ التعديل بنجاح` .. 
After that I should click another button but the problem appears when the internet connection is slow. I got the other button clicked before saving
How can I wait for the appearance of the value `تم حفظ التعديل بنجاح` and then after the appearance of that text >> move to the another button

Thanks advanced for help

Comment: Would something like this work 

Do until  InStr(Hyperlink.innertext, "Your_Value_Here") > 0 Then
     Application.Wait Now + #0:00:01#
Loop

Comment: Excel VBA is not the best tool for this job. If you haven't written code yet I would recommend using Python where there are existing HTTP libraries to do what you are trying to do here. The results from Python could be put in to an Excel table or Access table where you can continue with your Excel workflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot HackSlahs. I already wrote most of the code in VBA. @Ziggus I am still confused about that part Hyperlink.innertext as this is not a hyperlink. this is a label that only appears with that value after clicking Save button

Comment: Wrong information @ HackSlash!!!! Be it python or whatever, there is no such language which can interact with dynamic content through HTTP libraries. There are always selenium or puppeteer or any browser simulator like that running in the background or foreground to do the trick in such very cases. So, I don't find vba a wrong language to go with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would re-write this as you risk an infinite loop. Make it a timed loop and add in a `DoEvents`.

```
Dim result As String, testElement As Object, t As Date
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10 '<==adjust time here
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set testElement = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2")
    result = testElement.Text
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop While result <> "تم حفظ التعديل بنجاح"
```

Answer (score 5):

I have tried this solution and it worked well for me
This was with the help of Ziggus' suggestion

```
Do Until .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2").Text = "تم حفظ التعديل بنجاح"
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Loop
```