# VBA Automation (macro) isn't working very well on IE tabs

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I'm new here and on VBA, it's my 2nd post and I don't speak english very well. So, please, take easy on me =D

Last week I was having some troubles trying to automatize some procedures on IE. My macro worked very well when opened on **new windows**, but when I tried to run the same macro **on tabs** it wasn't working. It seemed (maybe) the macro wasn't recognizing the actual tab. I post that problem here and a wonderfull guy called  Deepak-MSFT helped me a lot. He taught me how to run the macro on tabs and it worked almost 100%.

**Problems:**

**1 -** The macro sometimes work, sometimes doesn't. Yesterday, for example, I was getting errors 424, 91 and, sometimes, it just opened another tab without insert the value (perheaps because of the "On Error Resume Next"). I think it was because one of the websites was slow. I tried to increase the TimeValue until 7 seconds but, even so, it didn't work. I tested during the whole day and it was extremely unstable, sometimes worked, and somtimes it doesn't. But today it's working (all the websites are stable). Any idea how to solve this instability?

**2 -** There are 2 websites (2nd and 3rd) where I use querySelector to find the box to insert the value. Both of them work on 70% of the PC's of my company and only those 2 websites doesn't work on the other 30%. I installed the same version of IE (11.0.9600), Excel (2007, SP3) and Windows (W7) on all of them, but even so, only those 2 websites with queryselector don't work. There are no errors. The macro just don't insert the value. Perhaps I'm missing something that make queryselector works on those PC's, but all the references match. I dig the first 5 pages on google trying to find a solution but I failed. I think there's a witch flying around those PC's. Could you help me?

**3 -**  I have total instability trying to run my macros on Excel 2016 or other versions of Excel higher than 2007 at Windows 10. Does anyone have a good solution to adapt the program to run on Excel 2016 (all my company will run this version next year) without have to do all over again?

Thank you very much guys. Here is my code:

```
Sub ademo()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


    IE.Visible = True

    'TAB 1

    URL = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/ConsultaPublicaAreasEmbargadas.php"


    IE.Navigate2 URL

    Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until


    IE.document.getElementById("num_cpf_cnpj").Value = "demo1" 'Sheets("Main").Range("C10")
    IE.document.getElementById("Emitir_Certificado").Click



 'TAB 2 - DAP

    On Error Resume Next
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate2 "http://smap14.mda.gov.br/extratodap/", 2048&


    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

    Set IE = GetIE("http://smap14.mda.gov.br/extratodap/")

    Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        Set doc = IE.document

        On Error Resume Next
        Set Target = IE.document.querySelector("#corpo > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > button")
        Target.Click
            Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
            Loop
            doc.getElementById("txtCPF_CNPJ").Value = "demo2"




    'TAB 3 - CNDT

    IE.Visible = True
    On Error Resume Next
    IE.Navigate2 "http://aplicacao.jt.jus.br/cndtCertidao/inicio.faces", 2048&


    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

    Set IE = GetIE("http://aplicacao.jt.jus.br/cndtCertidao/inicio.faces")

    Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        Set doc = IE.document

        On Error Resume Next
        Set target2 = IE.document.querySelector("#corpo > div > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")
        target2.Click
            Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
            Loop
            doc.getElementById("gerarCertidaoForm:cpfCnpj").Value = "demo3"






    'TAB 4 - CND

    On Error Resume Next
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate2 "http://servicos.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Servicos/certidao/CNDConjuntaInter/InformaNICertidao.asp?tipo=2", 2048&


    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

    Set IE = GetIE("http://servicos.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Servicos/certidao/CNDConjuntaInter/InformaNICertidao.asp?tipo=2")

    Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        Set doc = IE.document

        On Error Resume Next
        IE.document.getElementsByName("NI")(0).Value = "demo4"



    'TAB 5 - IMPROBIDADE

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate2 "http://www.cnj.jus.br/improbidade_adm/consultar_requerido.php?validar=form", 2048&


    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

    Set IE = GetIE("http://www.cnj.jus.br/improbidade_adm/consultar_requerido.php?validar=form")

    IE.document.getElementById("num_cpf_cnpj").Value = "demo5"



End Sub


Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim retVal As Object

    Set retVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next  'because may not have a "document" property
        'Check the URL and if it's the one you want then
        ' assign the window object to the return value and exit the loop
        sURL = o.document.Location
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
            Set retVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = retVal

End Function
```

Comment: 1) I think we need a clearer idea of what you are trying to achieve 2) why do you need to do this in different tabs? 3) Get rid of those On Error Resume Next lines and then see what info you get back that might illuminate why in some cases querySelector is not leading to values being inserted.

Comment: "X isn't working well on IE..." ...sounds about right. :P

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by QHarr. Is is necessary for you to open multiple tabs? If not, you can try to open different web pages in the same tab after finishing the processing for specific web page. By this way, you will not face tabs related issue.

Comment: 4) Replace all those Do Loops with proper page load waits i.e. While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents:Wend. Don't double up on these lines as either it meets the conditions or it doesn't.  If it doesn't then it is likely you need to consider a timed loop rather than a different type of Do Loop/repeating the same loop structure again.

Comment: Hi guys. First I _REALLY_ appreciate all your help. I'm so sorry if I express myself in a wrong way in my text. I'll do my best now!
@QHarr - thx, buddy. I did a Pilot in my company with almost 500 people open on windows. Almost everybody asked for the tabs. The purpose of the program is to optmize repetitive processes that we are obliged to do due to regulations. Accord to them, open in tabs increase productivity and organization. And they need to print pdfs of all webpages, open in tabs allow the company to use an app (the only one allowed by the company) that join a lot pdf's ONLY in tabs

Comment: continue.. @QHarr, sry I asked first your 2nd question. So, about the 1st, 
our country requires our company to consult a lot of websites to do our business activity, inserting id's on them and printing pdf's. It's a huge amount of consults (more than 5k per day). So we need to optimize using the resources that we have (limited amount of apps that are allowed here). We have that app (only one allowed) that join pdf's only if the consults were opened on tabs, not windows. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: continue... 3) I did this. Once I did, somtimes I got 424 error, sometimes I got nothing, it just didn't insert the value and there was no error (only with those 2 pages that use querySelector). And that's tremendously wierd because it works on 70% of the computers here, but I really need to make to work on 100% (all of them have the same version of all apps evolved). 4) Thanks, I'll do some stress tests today using this suggestion. Thx a lot Deepak and QHarr, I REALLY appreciate your help guys, really really. If you have more ideas to solve those problems, please help me a little more =D

Comment: Could still be a timing issue in both cases. querySelector is an optimized method which may be matching the node when present but data not retained - do you have significantly different connection speeds on these machines? Have you tried used timed loop for element to be present and to change value? Have you also tried setting the value via javascript executed through document.parentWindow.execScript

Comment: I have been doiing some stress tests modifying that line "Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))" from 3 to 8 seconds. Failed. Still sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.
"do you have significantly different connection speeds on these machines?" - No. same connection for all.
"Have you tried used timed loop for element to be present and to change value?" I didn't understand what you said, about time loop my only test is that one that I mentioned in the beggining (Deepak taugh me that one).

Comment: "Have you also tried setting the value via javascript executed through document.parentWindow.execScript" - I have no idea what is that, sounds like chinese for me, sry, I'm still a noob, but I love to learn if you have some time to teach me =D

Comment: On the machines that are failing - do they work if you execute the code slowly line by line with F8?   Re: other points see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396709/how-to-replace-or-update-style-attribute-value-by-using-vba/55396831#55396831) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53894221/6241235) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=timed+loop+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: No, using the F8 there's always errors on the queryselector line when I debug, I'll try to see if the points 1, 2 and 3 works, thanks!

Comment: Can you please inform us the error you got? For testing purposes, try to access the elements using any other way instead of query selector to see whether it is making any difference.

Comment: Hi guys! Good morning. @Deepak-MSFT - To access those 2 websites and insert the ID's I need to click in a button before. On the first website the button stays inside an iframe. On the other I couldn't click the button because I couldn't find the ID. I tried a lot of solutions, all failed. The only solution that worked was queryselector. If you have any alternatives about how to click those buttons It would help me a lot. Here is the websites "http://smap14.mda.gov.br/extratodap/" Button "Pessoa Física" and "http://www.tst.jus.br/certidao" Button "Emitir Certidão". Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: An alternative way for the first link is to loop through the elements and find it using its property like its title or using its innerHTML. In the second link, you can try to access that element using its name. I suggest you to first make this test separately and then try to add it in your original code. Also, try to open these two pages in last when you add it in your original code.